# Complex integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Let $f$ be an analytic function, $C^1$ on an open and connected set $U$.

for all $z\in U$ : $|f(z)-1|<1$.

Prove that $\int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz =0$ for every closed curve (closed curve- $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$) in $U$.

Any **hints**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The complex logarithm admits an analytic branch on $U_1(1)$.

**Edit:** Alternatively, by the definition of the line integral we have
$$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{f(x)} f'(x) \, dx = \int_a^b \frac{1}{f(\gamma(x))} f'(\gamma(x)) \gamma'(x) \, dx = \int_{\beta} \frac{1}{x} \, dx,$$
where $\beta = f \circ \gamma$. Now use the Cauchy integral theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by $U_1(1)$?

Comment: $U_r(x_0)$ denotes the open ball of radius $r$ around $x_0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just can't see how it helps..

Comment: $\log(f)$ is an antiderivative of $\frac{f'}{f}$.

Comment: Can i say this -  $\int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz =\int_\gamma log(f(z))'dz=log(\gamma(b))-\log(\gamma(a))=0$?

Comment: Yes, if you know that the logarithm is analytical on $U_1(1)$.

Comment: But where do we use the fact that $|f(z)-1|<1$?

Comment: To guarantee that the logarithm has an antiderivative. It seems that you haven't covered the complex logarithm as of yet, I will update my answer with an alternative proof.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer, which I can't understand why is downvoted, is correct. You can also argue as follows:

The condition $\;|f(z)-1|<1\;,\;\;\forall\,z\in U\;$, makes sure the function $\;f\;$ can **not** vanish in $\;U\;$ (why?), and thus $\;\cfrac{f'}f\;$ is analytic in $\;U\;$ , so the claim follws directly from CIT.

Comment: The function $f$ wont vanish because if it does then $1<1$?(I'm not the one who downvoted the other answer).

Comment: @ChakaChaka You are right...and didn't think you were the downvoter. Some rogue member of the site must be bored on christmas...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
To be able to use the fact that `Log(f)` is the antiderivative of `f′/f`, i.e. to be able to say that `(Log(f))' = f'/f`, you need to make sure that `Log(f)` is differentiable.

Yet, the complex logarithm `Log` is not continuous everywhere (and hence not differentiable everywhere).

The condition `|f(z)−1|<1` can be used to guarantee that `Log` is continuous and differentiable.

Does this make sense ?

Comment: $|f(z)-1|<1$ make sure that $f$ wont vanish, and that's why $Log$ is continuous and differentiable correct?