# Show that for holomorphic $f$ on an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ $\int_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set and $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function with $$f(U) \subseteq \{re^{it}: r> 0, -\pi<t<\pi\}$$ for all $z$. I want to show that:
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz = 0$$
for all closed smooth paths $\gamma$ in $U$.

The integrand can have no singularities, as the quotient of holomorphic functions it must again be holomorphic. However, Cauchy's integral theorem requires $U$ to be simply connected, which isn't stated in the definition of $U$.

My second attempt was to show that $f =\exp$ using the identity theorem. But that doesn't seem to apply, as $f$ may take any value except for the reals $\le 0$ over $U$.

Is there something we can use to apply Cauchy's integral theorem? Is there another method?

Comment: With the condition on the image of $f$, $\log f$ is well-defined.

Comment: For the benefit of OP let me also add that the integral of a derivative over  closed path is $0$ in any region, simply connected or not.

Comment: You can use the same arguments as in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2071402/42969.

Comment: This follows from the argument principle, see: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle

Comment: @MartinR Yes, thank you.